# Teradata: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group on.... i'm selecting all non aggregate fields

Tags: sql, teradata, aggregate-functions

This is driving me crazy. Can someone help me figure out why I keep getting a "non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group" error? It doesn't really make sense. I can't group on window functions, so the only two selected fields that are non aggregates are the first two. The inner query is completely fine, the error just happens when i run the whole thing. I also tried using the actual field names vs numeric order and i get the same error as if I should be grouping by something else.

```
select
end_of_week, 
deal_id, 
sum(sum_nob) as sum_nob, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum_nob desc) AS row_num
from ( 
    select
    td_week_end (report_date) as end_of_week, 
    report_date, 
    deal_id, 
    sum (nob) as sum_nob
    from sandbox.rev_mgmt_deal_funnel df
    left join (
        select 
        deal_uuid  
        from sandbox.sup_analytics_deal_counts_final) s on df.deal_id = s.deal_uuid 

    where s.deal_uuid is null
    and grt_l3 = 'L3 - High End'
    and report_date >= '2019-10-01'
    group by end_of_week, 
    report_date, 
    deal_id) a
group by 1,2
```

Comment: You can use an aliased column name in Teradata, but the parser only checks the alias lst when there's no matching column name. In your case the `sum(sum_nob) as sum_nob` adds an alias, but it's the same name as the base column, thus `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum_nob desc)` matches the base column. Both answer show the fix, you could also apply a different alias name. Of course, Gordon is right, your current query is overly complex

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems much more complicated than necessary:

```
select td_week_end(report_date) as end_of_week, 
       deal_id, 
       sum(nob) as sum_nob,
       row_number() over (order by sum(nob)) as row_num
from sandbox.rev_mgmt_deal_funnel df left join
     sandbox.sup_analytics_deal_counts_final s
     on df.deal_id = s.deal_uuid 
where s.deal_uuid is null and
      grt_l3 = 'L3 - High End' and
      report_date >= '2019-10-01'
group by 1, 2;
```

Notes:

- No subquery is necessary.
- There is no need to aggregate twice.
- The subquery for the `left join` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `ROW_NUMBER()`, whose partition clause contains a non-aggregated column (`sum_nob`).

I think that you want:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(sum_nob) DESC) AS row_num
```

This will give you a ranking of records based on *the sum of* their `sum_nob`.